# How to change images one by one Kind of cycles through every 3-4 seconds

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Hello Friend i am working on an application where i need to rotate images through the 5/6 pages of view Kind of cycles through every 3-4 seconds...I need the access to change the image as well.Please provide me some sample code..

Comment: "Please provide me some sample code.." - no-no, you read some documentation first.

Comment: which documentation i need to read could you please tell me

Comment: @raxpo UIImageView mostly, but I suspect you also need a fresh breath of general iOS- and Cocoa Touch-programming related refresher.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know how to use `UIImageView` and set images? If not, please refer to the [`UIImageView` class reference guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which describes the interface, and if you look at the "related sample code", you can see it action.

In terms of how to change an image every few seconds, you might first define an instance variable or class property for your `NSTimer`:

```
NSTimer *timer;
```

Then will probably create a recurring timer, e.g. something like:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.5
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(changeImage)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];
```

Clearly, this presumes that you have written your own method, `changeImage` that will change the image of the `UIImageView` to the next image.

Finally, don't forget to `invalidate` your timer when you want to dismiss your view controller (e.g., in `willWillDisappear`, *not* `dealloc`), because the use of `self` in the timer causes a strong reference cycle, and your memory won't be released if you don't.

And, if any of this doesn't make sense, I will second what others have suggested, that you might want to do some more basic iOS tutorials. Not to be rude, but we're here to help you answer questions with your existing code, not write new code for you. And if you don't have mastery of some of the more mundane aspects of iOS programming (views, view controllers, memory management, etc.), doing something more sophisticated is probably going to be a frustrating exercise for everyone.